# Extract a format of date from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to **extract** a date of birth from a given string.
The format is always `"ddMMMyy" (for example "22NOV83")`.

The problem is that there could be other chars before and after the dob.
possible inputs are : `"DOB: 22NOV83", "CUSTOMER A DOB: 22NOV", "22NOV83 BLA BLA"`

I think that by using this Regex:

```
^\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}$
```

I can check if a string mathces a date , **But how to check if a part of a string mathces a date and than extract it ?**

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You said that the format is **always** "ddMMMyy", yet one of your examples is only "22NOV". Was that a typo?

Comment: Will it only be the DOB field that will start with a number? Or is there any chance that other fields too might start with or contain numbers?

Comment: @Enigmativity well yes and no.... if i get 22NOV it just won't be a valid date time. but it was a typo :)

Comment: @AJ there is a chance that there will be other digits in the string

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "^" and "$"

`Regex.Match( "CUSTOMER A DOB: 22NOV99 blah", @"\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}" );`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little snippet that should help. Note you could use `Regex.Match()` with further groups in the regex pattern to perform further validation. Also, if other data could possibly have valid dates outside of the data you wish to extract, that would further complicate the process.

```
  var extractedDates = new List<DateTime>();

  foreach (var s in inputs) {
    var m = Regex.Match(s, @"(\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{2})");
    if (m.Groups.Count == 1) {
      // No match
      continue;
    }
    try { 
      extractedDates.Add(DateTime.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value));
    } catch (FormatException) {
      // Regex matched but something else was wrong, i.e. 98ALS98
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Pattern to match the date

```
  (?:[DOB:]?\s+(\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
    DateTime d = new DateTime();
    string s = "CUSTOMER A DOB: 22NOV83"; // any string that contains date in <dd><3 chars of Month><YY>
    string date = s.Substring(s.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray()),7);
    d = DateTime.Parse(date);
    Response.Write(d);
```

variable 'date' will have the date in string and 'd' will have it in DateTime.

Again this will be helpful if the no other strings will have numbers.

OR
with regex other fields with numbers are no issue:

```
string s = "your input";
    Match d = Regex.Match(s, @"\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}");
    Response.Write(d);
```

Let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries instead of anchors:

```
\b(\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2})\b
```

The DOB is in group 1.